# Populate WPF listbox based on selection of another listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a listbox that is bound to an observablecollection. The observable collection contains a list of objects, each with it's own observablecollection. What i want is to click an item in the first listbox and have it's list of things displayed in the second listbox. Can I do this in pure WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind the ItemsSource of the second listbox to the SelectedItem of the first list box.

Edit: here is some code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        TestItems = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            TestItems.Add(InitTest(i));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Test> TestItems { get; set; }

    private Test InitTest(int index)
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.Name  = "Test" + index.ToString();
        test.Test2Items =  new ObservableCollection<Test2>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
        {
            Test2 test2 = new Test2();
            test2.Label = test.Name + "_label" + i.ToString();
            test.Test2Items.Add(test2);
        }
        return test;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Test2> Test2Items { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

public class Test2
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Label;
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        x:Name="MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WPF Example" Height="300" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding TestItems, ElementName=MyWindow}" />
        <ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Test2Items, ElementName=ListBox1}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: The selecteditem is an object that has an observable collection inside of it. The observable collection is what i want to bind to the second listbox, but I dont know how.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know I could do this...

    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Test2Items

Answer (score 0):

Your view models could look something like this: (I am using my [BindableBase](http://northhorizon.net/2011/the-right-way-to-do-inotifypropertychanged/) here)

```
class MainViewModel : Bindablebase {
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }

    private ItemViewModel _selectedItem;
    public ItemViewModel SelectedItem {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value, "SelectedItem"); }
    }
}

class ItemViewModel : BindableBase {
    public ItemViewModel (string name) {
        Name = name;
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Values { get; private set; }

    private string _selectedValue;
    public string SelectedValue {
        get { return _selectedValue; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedValue, value, "SelectedValue"); }
    }
}
```

And then your view would have:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>

<!-- 
Note that the DataContext here could be ommitted
and the bindings would be like {Binding SelectedItem.Values}
-->
<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue}"/>
```