# Binding for nested data

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a class

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public List<Data1> ListData1 {get; set;}
}

public class Data1
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public List<Data2> ListData2 { get; set; }
}

public class Data2
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

data must be displayed in the following form

[image]

I do so - to link an MyData ListBox filled with data. For him, pointing DataTemplate, bring the code

```
            <!--  MyData  -->
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Caption}" />

            </Grid>

            <!--  Data1  -->
            <ListBox 
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     DisplayMemberPath = "FirstName"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding ListData1 }" />
            <!--  -->        

            <!--  Data2  -->
            <ListBox x:Name="lbData2"
                     Grid.Column="2"
                     DisplayMemberPath = "LastName"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding ????}" />

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

How to Make Binding for lbData2? ListData1.ListData2 option does not work.

Comment: Please, review this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919262/populate-wpf-listbox-based-on-selection-of-another-listbox) (and its answer). I think that it may  help you.

Comment: did you check HierarchicalDataTemplate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can just use the following binding syntax:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ListData1/ListData2}"
```

This means bind to the `ListData2` property of current or selected instance of `ListData1`.

You can find out more from the [Binding.Path Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) page at MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

If  you do not want to change anything in ViewModel, you can do this on XAML only:

```
<!--  Data1  -->
        <ListBox x:Name="firstNamelbx"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 DisplayMemberPath = "FirstName"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ListData1 }" />
        <!--  -->        

        <!--  Data2  -->
        <ListBox x:Name="lbData2" Grid.Column="2"
                 DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=firstNamelbx}"
                 DisplayMemberPath = "LastName"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ListData2}" />
```

I think the better way is either you add a SelectedFirstName property in view model and bind it with first name list box's selected item, or use ICollectionView instead of List and sync its CurrentItem with first name list box.

Comment: Thank you it works, but I need CurrentItem rather than SelectedItem

Comment: I came back to this problem. Binding is work(Binding ListData1/ListData2). Now I need to make the alignment of rows in height. Any ideas?

Comment: @FetFrumos, can you describe with more details? How do you want to align two lists?